# Paper js hittest doesn't work in Compound Path as I expect

Tags: paperjs

In paper js I've created a compound path and now I want to implement drag and drop on it. The compound path has two children (two circles).
Here's the issue: when I attach a mouse event to the compound path (using hittest to get the whole path), and click on it, I get the reference only  to the first child path. If I click on the second child path, the hittest returns undefined, while I'd like to get the compound path.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Francesco R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but there are few ways to make it work.

1. I assume you use [Tool](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool). If so, you can try to get the item not by hit testing, but using [ToolEvent](http://paperjs.org/reference/toolevent)'s `item` object

   example:

   ```
   mousedown: function (event) {
       if (event.item) {
           // event.item is what you need
       }
   },
   ```
2. If you know what item you'll be hit testing - for example you want to check if user clicked on a specific item, you can call `hitTest()` from this item

   example:

   ```
   mousedown: function (event) {
       var hit = yourItem.hitTest(event.point, { tolerance: 10 });
       if (hit) {
           // now you can use hit.item or yourItem ('cos you know the item)
       }
   },
   ```
3. You can try [hitTest options](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#hittest-point). There you can specify what class of items are you looking for:

   > **options.class**: Only hit test again a certain item class and its sub-classes: *Group*, *Layer*, *Path*, *CompoundPath*, *Shape*, *Raster*, *PlacedSymbol*, *PointText*, etc.

Tell me if that helps or provide some test case. You can create a [paperscript sketch here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/) and provide us the link you get in your adress bar after running your sketch.

EDIT: Actually I've created a sketch for you, showing those methods: [look here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)